# how to set the floating action button

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I am trying to learn circular floating action button but I am getting error in Builder here is my code for setting floating action button. I have taken the compile time dependency.How to fix the error?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    // in Activity Context
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_sub_action);
    FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(icon)
            .build();
    ImageView icon1 = new ImageView(this);
    icon1.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action_dark_selector);
    ImageView icon2 = new ImageView(this);
    icon2.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action_dark_selector);
    ImageView icon3 = new ImageView(this);
    icon3.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action_dark_selector);

    SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);

    SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon1).build();
    SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon2).build();
    SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon3).build();

    FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
            .addSubActionView(button1)
            .addSubActionView(button2)
            .addSubActionView(button3)
            .attachTo(actionButton)
            .build();

}
```

Comment: Fab is included in one of the templates of android studio, just create a project with that template then study the code.

Comment: literally, just listen to @gj_ . Create a new **blank** activity, and you'll get the floating button!

Comment: thx gj_ and every one I am new In android thats y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon1).build();
      SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon2).build();
      SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(icon3).build();
```

After button Add this code.

```
      button1.setOnClickListener(this);
      button2.setOnClickListener(this);
      button3.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Comment: @Neelay Srivastava look my answer.